# simple_copy example on pmem.io

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have created the emulated device given at http://pmem.io/2016/02/22/pm-emulation.html, successfully.

It shows the device correctly:

```
:~/Prakash/nvml/src/examples/libpmem$ mount | grep pmem
```

/dev/pmem0 on /mnt/pmemd type ext4 (rw,relatime,dax,errors=continue,data=ordered)

However, when I execute the simple_copy sample given with pmem nvml, it gives this error:

> amd@amd:~/Prakash/nvml/src/examples/libpmem$ ./simple_copy logs
>
> /dev/pmem0 pmem_map_file: File exists
>
> amd@amd:~/Prakash/nvml/src/examples/libpmem$ ./simple_copy logs
>
> /dev/pmem0/logs pmem_map_file: Not a directory

Am I not using the program correctly?

Also, I have mounted the device as dax and I clearly see the performance advantage with

```
:~/Prakash/nvml/src/examples/libpmem$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/pmem0 bs=2G count=1
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
2147479552 bytes (2.1 GB, 2.0 GiB) copied, 0.910729 s, 2.4 GB/s
:~/Prakash/nvml/src/examples/libpmem$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pmem0/test bs=2G count=1
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
2147479552 bytes (2.1 GB, 2.0 GiB) copied, 6.39032 s, 336 MB/s
```

Comment: can you point the source code of `simple_copy` ? which you used

Comment: It is the same sample which comes in nvml library at path nvml/src/examples/libpmem/simple_copy.c. I have not modified the sample.

Answer (score 0):

from the errors posted, is seems reasonable to believe:

1. without the appropriate option, it will not create a directory
2. without the appropriate option, it will not replace a file

Answer (score 0):

If you open the example you are referring to, you will see the following:

```
if ((pmemaddr = pmem_map_file(argv[2], BUF_LEN,
            PMEM_FILE_CREATE|PMEM_FILE_EXCL,
            0666, &mapped_len, &is_pmem)) == NULL) {
    perror("pmem_map_file");
    exit(1);
}
```

This is the part that is giving you trouble. To understand why, let's look at the `man 7 libpmem`. You can find the relevant part [here](http://pmem.io/pmdk/manpages/linux/master/libpmem/pmem_is_pmem.3).

This is the paragraph we are interested in:

> The pmem_map_file() function creates a new read/write mapping for a
>   file. If PMEM_FILE_CREATE is not specified in flags, the entire
>   existing file path is mapped, len must be zero, and mode is ignored.
>   Otherwise, path is opened or created as specified by flags and mode,
>   and len must be non-zero. pmem_map_file() maps the file using mmap(2),
>   but it also takes extra steps to make large page mappings more likely.

So, the `pmem_map_file` function effectively calls `open(2)` and then `mmap(2)`. In the `simple_copy.c` example we can observe that the flags which were used are: `PMEM_FILE_CREATE` and `PMEM_FILE_EXCL`, and as we can learn from the manpage, they roughly translate to `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` respectively.
This means that the error messages are correct and you've received them because in your first attempt you've provided an existing file, whilst on the second attempt you tried a directory.

There's an in-depth explanation of libpmem [here](http://pmem.io/pmdk/libpmem/).